# Questions about sound mixers

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question which is basically purely about sound mixer, it's draft is below. I'm not sure whether it can be posted on any of the sound-related sites. There is:

- [sound.SE](http://sound.stackexchange.com), but they seem to reject questions about microphones and mixing equipment unless they are obviously related to sound design
- [music.SE](http://music.stackexchange.com), but this question would be probably too far from "music performance" to be considered there
- [video.SE](http://video.stackexchange.com), but it seems out of question here immediately
- and mentioned in comments and answers: [amateurRadio.SE](http://ham.stackexchange.com), [signalProcessing.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Do I miss any site where such question could be posted? Is it actually on-topic on one of the mentioned sites?

---

**Now the question itself:**

---

I would like to know what are exact characteristics of the mixer's 3-zone EQs, namely of the one of Behringer Xenyx802. My problem is the following: I plan to get a microphone (Shure SM35), but its frequency response is not quite flat (see the dashed line below):

[image]

The EQ offers -15dB on LOW (80Hz), which would nicely cancel out the mic's increased response on basses. However, it's not clear what happnes with a frequency at 1kHz (since the MID knob is at 2.5kHz). Therefore, I would like to know which frequencies are altered to what extent by the mixer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would consider that question on-topic at sound.SE. I read it as getting appropriately down into the details of frequency response of the various pieces of gear. In this instance, I don't really think context is relevant, even though as a rule, the context matters at sound.SE. The question (or perhaps more to the point, the answers) would be equally useful for studio, live, sound design, etc.

Having said all that, there are likely some that would disagree with me.

You'd get my upvote.

Comment: Thanks, posted: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/30076/mixer-eq-curves-specification-sheets I'll not accept this answer yet to keep the discussion about the scopes open.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having some scope issues with music.SE and sound.SE as well. Their scopes are much narrower than their names suggest. E.g. questions pertaining to DJing are rejected on both music.SE and sound.SE for whatever reason.

Anyway I believe you could also consider the [signals processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixer.

Comment: Well, it seems that sounding issues (mics, mixers, cables etc.) in general aren't acceptable on either site unless you explicitly prove that they're related to sound design or to music performing. That's like saying that monitor is not a part of a computer :-/